# Use only the mathbb font from TeX Gyre Pagella Math

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, mathpazo, tex-gyre-math, mathbb

I am working with LuaLaTeX on Debian stable, with `texlive-full` in the version `2018.20190227-2`. My main goal is to use the Palatino derivates. For pure text, this can easily be achieved by

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
```

However, I prefer a combination of `mathpazo` and `mathabx` instead of `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` (since some spacings look really weird in Pagella Math), whilst I rather prefer the `mathbb` font from Pagella Math. So my ideal combination would be the following:

- Use `mathpazo` and `mathabx`,
- Use the `mathbb` font from `TeX Gyre Pagella Math`.

Is there any possibility to achieve this? Unfortunately, `mathpazo` somehow ‘protects’ its `mathbb` font, and `unicode-math` overwrites too many other this, so the naïve approach

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{mathpazo,mathabx}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
   Brackets are too low in Pagella Math: $(X+Y)^2=X^2+2XY+Y^2$.

   This also looks weird in Pagella Math: Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a map.

   This is supposed to be Pagella Math: $\mathbb{R}$
\end{document}
```

will give the complete opposite: `mathbb` from Pazo and everything else from Pagella Math.

Answer (score 2):

You may try setting only the `bb` range:

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range=bb]
```

Comment: I guess you want the extra parameter in the middle? Unfortunately, both versions cause the error ```Package unicode-math Error: No main maths font has been set up yet.```

Comment: The extra parameter is fine at the end. Looking at the [unicode-math manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf), section 4.4, you can try to use the legacy LaTeX commands or the wrappers that unicode-math provides.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try Asana Math, which is based on Pazo.